# byobu: How can I create a new session in an existing tmux group?

Tags: tmux, byobu

We are using `byobu` here in our embedded development team to share access to the programmers that are connected to our devices. That way all of our team have access to the device log files and so on.

This worked quite well so far. Every member could log in into a common account on that computer and start `byobu` to check the log files. Every user got a new session in an existing session group, so everyone could check the log file (=window) he is interested in.

It seems the session management of byobu has changed several times within the last year, and byobu is now always connecting directly to an existing session. For some time the behaviour could be selected by creating a `.reuse-session` file in byobu's configuration folder.

In current versions of byobu this doesn't seem to be supported anymore. When I check [`select-session.py`](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/lib/byobu/include/select-session.py#L43) I see in line 43 that the file still gets tested, but the result variable `reuse_sessions` isn't used anywhere. byobu always calls `tmux -u attach …`.

By that when one user changes the shown window in the session, all other users in this one session get the current window changed as well. This makes it impossible to let different people work at the same time.

How can we resume to having different sessions sharing only the session group? Currently I can only get this by using `tmux` directly, but that doesn't seem to be the purpose of byobu.

Comment: Author of Byobu here.  Hmm, there's at least one bug in there (the fact that reuse_sessions variable isn't used any more).  What is the behavior you desire?  Every developer gets their own unique session?

Comment: @DustinKirkland Each developer gets its own session in a shared group. So we have access to the same windows, but can switch independently from each other. We need the shared group, as we often want to access the same logs or work together on something. As a work-around I now create the sessions with `tmux new-session -t team -s dev_name` for each developer. After the sessions exist, byobu asks which session to use and we select our session by our developer name (dev_name).